# Play Mp3 from path stored in database using media player

Tags: android

Im creating alarm app So i need to play music at alarm time reached. now its working smoothly using Ringtone manager see the code below

```
 if(d1==1) {

        File k = new File(url);  // set File from path
        if (url != null) {      // file.exists

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ring");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, k.length());
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
                    .getAbsolutePath());
            context.getContentResolver().delete(
                    uri,
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\""
                            + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
            newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);



         //   Toast.makeText(context,""+period,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(period==0)
            {
                ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, newUri);
                ringtone.play();
            }
            else
            {
                new CountDownTimer(period*1000,1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        if (count==1)
                        {

                            ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, newUri);
                            ringtone.play();

                        }
                        count=count+1;


                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        ringtone.stop();
                    }
                }.start();

            }
```

Now i want to play this music using media player i use below code that is not working

```
                try {
                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, newUri);
                final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) != 0) {
                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
```

please anyone show me a solution

Comment: can you put some logs ?

Comment: not getting any log about this...but app still running...if use media player its not playing sound